# Adding bulk values to SQL Server database with c# winform

Tags: c#, sql, bulkinsert, sql-server-2008-express

I'm using SQL Server 2008 Express.

What is the best way to import bulk values into the database from a C# app?

Right now I have some textboxes and I can import data without any problem. And I would like to import not only one row ,by "click to a button" but 3 or 4.

Please help me!

Comment: SqlBulkCopy. Google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 3 or 4 rows, I would suggest setting up a `SqlCommand` with a parameterized insert statement, creating and binding parameters for the inserted columns, and then calling [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can retain the same `SqlCommand` and `SqlParameters` objects, reassign new values to the `SqlParameter`s, and then do the next `ExecuteNonQuery` for the next row.

However, if you are doing a much larger insert (as in 100k rows at a time), you should look at using [`SqlBulkCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) - this allows for high performance bulk inserts (and only inserts) into a table.